# react-native run-android after config jetifier

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not find androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :app > project :react-native-reanimated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
  insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not find androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :app > project :react-native-reanimated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
  insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

PS C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 928 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not find androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :app > project :react-native-reanimated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
  insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not find androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/.m2/repository/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/k7aled/Desktop/reactnative/test2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/transition/transition/1.0.0/transition-1.0.0.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :app > project :react-native-reanimated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
  insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

PS C:\Users\k7aled\Desktop\reactnative\test2>

Answer (score 0):

first add this two line to your android/gradle.properties :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

then run this two command line in your project root with terminal(cmd):

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```